# How do I create HTTPS page for CakePHP?

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp

I don't really understand the differences between HTTP and HTTPS except that HTTTPS encrypts the data transmission (I think, correct me if I am wrong). Now, I am about to get my Facebook Page Tab up and running. For this I need my Tab URL at my CakePHP app also to be accessible over HTTPS. How do I do that in CakePHP? Just writing an HTTPS instead of just HTTP in the URL doesn't do the job.

Comment: you must install a ssl certificate on the server. you can self sign it but then you get a warning in the browser. Else you have to buy one which is not cheap..

Comment: This is actually not a cakephp issue but a server-only issue. cake will work with https out of the box if you got the ssl setup (certificate, ssl routing) right on the server.

Comment: Aha I see. So in other words it will be difficult for me to implement the Facebook Page Tab because I don't really have a budget to buy a https certificate? Or do you know a way to avoid using https for the Facebook Page Tab?